# Ist "einzukaufen" richtig?

Tags: translation

Today I found an interesting word: `zusammenzuwohnen`. The sequence of thoughts have brought me to this sentence:

`Es ist leicht im Supermarkt einzukaufen`

Does it (`einzukaufen`) make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words *zusammenzuwohnen* and *einzukaufen* are *zu-Infinitive* of the separable verbs *zusammenwohnen* and *einkaufen*. All separable verbs build their *zu-Infinitiv* like this. For building the *zu-Infinitiv* of non-separable verbs, the *zu* is a separate word in front of the bare infinitive instead.

> Es ist leicht, im Supermarkt etwas zu kaufen.

---

Mind the comma, as the second part is a clause of its own:

> Es ist leicht, im Supermarkt einzukaufen.

Sometimes, the *zu-Infinitiv* is considered to be a part of the outer clause. The following sentences are all correct, with very subtle differences in meaning:

> Es ist hier leicht einzukaufen.
>
> Es ist hier leicht, einzukaufen.
>
> Es ist leicht, hier einzukaufen.

You get a feeling for it if you understand the German comma as a means to stop a thought and pick up another thought. Often, people will also mark it in speech with a short pause.

Comment: Danke Ihnen für die Erklärung!

Answer (score 1):

Whether it makes sense or not (**yes, it does make sense**!), the construction is regular, because the verb *einkaufen* is a composite.

Compare differently

> "Es ist wichtig, etwas in den Korb herein zu legen"
>
> "Etwas wurde in den Korb herein gelegt".

There "herein" is a normal adposition (a preposition I guess), because we can *lay things down, in, on, next to, etc*, and legen is always the same word. With *einkaufen*, the meaning of the preposition has been almost lost, it's not productive anymore.

Compare respectively *überlegen*, where the idiom is so strong, one might say *überlegen über etwas* "to think about something" (*überlegen* is tricky to translate alone, I prefer *ponder*). Also, *kaufen* doesn't usually take prepositions, except perhaps in *aufkaufen, auskaufen* "to buy out/up". The [Duden on the matter of compositions](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#K54) says for indecisive cases, different variants should be tolerated. So I'd have to tolerate *zusammenwohnen* and that might actually have a stronger meaning, implying a stronger connection than merely living in the same apartment. Likewise, "hereinlegen" means *to trick someone* (figuratively *to lay someone into a trap*, though I suppose there had been a connotation from *to lock in a trap* and *locken* "to lure"). It doesn't help the analysis that *herein* is also a composition, because, we do have *einlegen* (*Einlagen*), *einlagern*, etc.

Further, *zugeben* "admit" is not the same as "etwas zu geben", and not the same as *hinzu/dazu geben* (whence *Zugabe* "encore") either. Yet we might write "sich hinzugeben" (for *Hingabe*).

I didn't learn the old orthography, so I can't say what alternatives exist for spacing. I'm only guessing that verbs that became nouns like "Ablage"

Now the funny bit, why "zu" is placed in the middle of the verb. Well, the prefix is still recognized. Compare *mit Ihr zusammen zu wohnen*. Again, we can see a reduplication of a preposition. One *zu* binds stronger to the object to left and most strongest to *-sammen*, which is not anymore recognized as the word similar to *Summe* "sum" that it is really is, but that other *zu* binds stronger to the verb.

There's probably a syntax theory to explain this concisely.

Comment: Note *herein* denotes a direction of "into and towards me", while *hinein* denotes "into". So, "etwas in einen Korb hereinlegen" implies you're sitting in the basket. Welcome to the site, BTW!

Comment: @tofro* Ich kann auch etwas in den Korb hier, genau den hier, rein legen*. But you are correct of course, if rein stems from this use of *herein*, so that it is an after-thought, not the source of the composite

Comment: Vergleich auch *Ausflug*, mit zumindest *Flug* von der gleichen Wurzel wie *Flucht*, wenn nicht sogar die Zusammensetzungen gemeinsamen Ursprung haben. Vergleiche ferner *Abenteuer, abenteuerliche Entschuldigungen*. Ob da tatsächlich ein enger Zusammenhang besteht ist aber irrelevant, denn es ging mir um den Bezug zu *escape* bzw. den Formen in allerlei anderen Sprachen. Die Herkunft von *escape* ist ohnehin nicht klar. Die Annahme von *cappa - Manter* ist ... what? *capio* "capture, grab* liegt viel näher, *ex*+*capio* wäre halt das Gegenteil zu *ergreifen*. Vgl. *was nimmst du dir heraus?*

Comment: Und das passt auch zum Pferd, im Sinne *nicht im Griff haben*.